# How can I import custom js files of my project inside vuejs 3 component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component

I want to import custom js file in vue3 component. Please, Help me out for fixing my the problem.

I have try this:

```
<template></template>
<script src="filePath/file.js"></script>
<script>
import 'filePath/file.js';

export default{
    name: 'Component Name'
}

</script>
```

```
<template></template>
<script>
import 'filePath/file.js';

export default{
    name: 'Component Name'
}

</script>
```

Some where I saw the answer like

```
import ClassName from "src/Filename";
```

But my file has no class name, no export default, in this case what can I do?

I want like this.

```
<template></template>
<script>
import 'filePath/file.js';

export default{
    name: 'Component Name'
}

</script>
```